# Can .pem certificates have an encrypted certificate and an encrypted RSA key?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, certificate, openssl

Can `.pem` certificate file have an encrypted certificate and an encrypted private key?

e.g. Bag Attributes

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED CERTIFICATE-----

-----END ENCRYPTED CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is this format possible?

Comment: "Bag Attributes"? That's not a PEM thing. Are you confusing it with PKCS#12?

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to debate the exact definition of the PEM standard, the nearest formal definition of the it is [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468).  You won't find `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED CERTIFICATE-----` in there.  Also, why encrypt a certificate when it's a public document?

Therefore, the answer to your question is - "no".

However, with unencrypted certificates it's a "yes".  The following is acceptable:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```